# Error if use iframe in tabs (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

If I use iframe in my tab than only this error comes .

My code Look like this

```
        <div id="tabs2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs2-11">Attachments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs2-21">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs2-31">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="tabs2-11"><iframe id="iframe1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="" /></div>
          <div id="tabs2-21">
             Some text
          </div>
          <div id="tabs2-31">...Phase 2</div>
    </div>
```

If I remove iframe than it's working fine .

Comment: close `iframe` like this `</iframe>`

Comment: you didn't close iframe

Comment: Wow . Working ..  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing `iframe` like following should fix an issue, as `iframe` is not self closing element.

```
<iframe id="iframe1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="" ></iframe>
```